# I have a table view and i allowed multiple row selection and i want to display them on the next screen

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview

I have a table view and am passing data from sqlite database . I have enabled multiple row selection and i want to display the selected rows on the next screen. 
Think of it like a list of invoices and seeing what you selected on the next screen to make payment .

Here is code...

```
db.insert(invoice: "# invoice", mdate: "2012-05-15", currency: "KES", amount: "71.33")
db.insert(invoice: "# invoice 0035368216", mdate: "2018-08-23", currency: "USD", amount: "123.00")
db.insert(invoice: "# invoice 0076184599", mdate: "2018-10-03", currency: "USD", amount: "290.00")
db.insert(invoice: "# invoice 0076184592", mdate: "2019-08-23", currency: "USD", amount: "104.00")
db.insert(invoice: "# invoice 0035368231", mdate: "2019-11-23", currency: "USD", amount: "123.00")
db.insert(invoice: "# invoice 0076184673", mdate: "2019-11-23", currency: "USD", amount: "1205.00")
db.insert(invoice: "# invoice 0117430060", mdate: "2019-11-23", currency: "USD", amount: "756.00")


@objc func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {

    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: animated)
    }
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return payments.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell


    cell.invoiceLabel?.text = self.payments[indexPath.row].invoice
    cell.dateeLabel?.text = self.payments[indexPath.row].datee
    cell.currencyLabel.text = self.payments[indexPath.row].currency
    cell.amountLabel.text =  self.payments[indexPath.row].amount
    return cell
}
```